# C#- How to read a video/image file in SD card to use in an android application in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating an android application in Unity 5.4.0f3 and I am using some videos and images for the app. My problem is that my file size is too much bigger than a typical android app because the videos and images are in the assets. Someone tells me that it is possible for the app to just call these videos and images from the SD Card (outside of the file itself). How can I do this? I am an absolute beginner in Android development. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer in the unity forums:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/317048/android-writing-to-applicationpersistentdatapath.html

You can get the path to the SD-Card of the Android device by using

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

Remember to check that the path exists before trying to write files to it. Also note from the answers in the unity forum link that the path may or may not point to the SD-card depending on the specific Android device's settings.

Edit: From what I can find with some googling, most games that are large will have a small installer and then after having started will download the assets to the SD-card within the application and later use them in the game.

Comment: Thank you. I will visit the link you've shared.

Comment: Flipbed, I am curious about your last paragraph '"Edit: From what I can find with some googling, most games that are large will have a small installer and then after having started will download the assets to the SD-card within the application and later use them in the game.". Is this true?